# Will Apple replace the battery on an iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, battery

On Apple's [service pricing page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/iphone/repair/service/pricing), it says you can replace the batteries on the following models of iPhone for £45:

> iPhone SE
>
> iPhone 6
>
> iPhone 6 Plus
>
> iPhone 6s
>
> iPhone 6s Plus
>
> iPhone 7
>
> iPhone 7 Plus
>
> iPhone 8
>
> iPhone 8 Plus
>
> and all other eligible models

Does the iPhone 5s fall under *all other eligible models*, or is it too old?

Answer (score 1):

Although [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPhone) in March 2016, iPhone 5s is still supported for service and parts replacement by Apple (as of this writing).

Check with your local authorised service centre for availability.

Comment: Will cancel that Genius bar appointment then, thanks!

Comment: @JMK I think you should hold onto the appointment. I incorrectly inferred your question and posted an incorrect reply. I have edited the post. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.